# How can I find out exactly what my modeline is telling me?

Tags: mode-line, help, tooltip

I'd like to know exactly what my modeline is telling me and how it's derived. Right now, if I'm working with a graphical terminal I can hover over each modeline entry in turn, and if I'm lucky, a tooltip will pop up; obviously, this won't work in a console.  Alternately I can examine the `mode-line-format` variable, but it's not at all obvious how the values correlate to what's displayed.

Ideally I'd like something within Emacs that would explain, for example, how am I getting from `"%e"` in mode-line-format to `U:---`, what that means and where to get more information:  “`U:---` comes from `%e` in `mode-line-format` and means this, that and the other.  You can customize it here.”

Is there a mode or tool that will help me?

Comment: @asjo: The OP is looking to understand the mode line in detail, in particular, to understand `mode-line-format` better. That is in the Elisp manual, not the Emacs manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As far as I know, **there is no such tool** in Emacs or a 3rd-party library. But perhaps someone else will come up with one.
2. You have correctly pointed to the two main sources of info I would have mentioned: (1) pop-up info in tooltips and (2) studying `mode-line-format` and its doc (doc string and Elisp manual, node [`Mode Line Top`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Top.html#Mode-Line-Top)).

   A third source of info that can help is to see how existing code modifies `mode-line-format` and what it does with it. This can be helpful because of the complexity of `mode-line-format`.  There are lots of such code examples out there. Library [`modeline-posn.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/modeline-posn.el) is one of mine, but there are plenty of others, including code that is part of the Emacs distribution.
3. Please consider suggesting this as a possible enhancement to Emacs. You do that with `M-x report-emacs-bug` (it is not only for bug reports). And if you have any particular ideas of what features for this might be useful for users, please contribute them also.

   You can also send a mail to `emacs-devel@gnu.org`, which is the Emacs development mailing list, to open a discussion about this possibility.

   (There are other such complex structures in Emacs that could also benefit from additional help/exploration/navigation: menus & other keymaps, `font-lock-keywords`...  A generic means of, or framework for, exploring/interrogating such a structure might also be helpful.)

Answer (score 4):

Since any tool will have to read `mode-line-format`, you cannot do better than examining it. The manual has an extensive section describing the format **[here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html)** including all the `%` constructs.

Note that the `mode-line-format` is often recursive i.e. it contains variables which are themselves valid modeline formats so it is often useful to parse a part of it independently. For this case `format-mode-line` is a useful function which can give insight to what a particular snippet does.

Also note that many minor modes (`anzu-mode`, `helm` etc) will often add there own sections to the modelines which might not be evident from `mode-line-format` directly. Browsing customization options usually yields information on these.